# RSA algorithm implementation not working properly in java

Tags: java, encryption, rsa, biginteger, public-key-encryption

Theoretically I know that if `n=33`, `e(public key)=3` and `d(private key)=7` I can encrypt a `plaintext` by using `BigInteger` class with `modPow(e, n)`, and decrypt with `modPow(d,n)`, but after decryption `plaintext` is not the same as first.

Here is my code:

```
  public class KeyTest {
private BigInteger n = new BigInteger("33");
private BigInteger e = new BigInteger("3");
private BigInteger d = new BigInteger("7");

public static void main(String[] args) {
    KeyTest test = new KeyTest();

    BigInteger plaintext = new BigInteger("55");
    System.out.println("Plain text: " + plaintext);

    BigInteger ciphertext = test.encrypt(plaintext);
    System.out.println("Ciphertext: " + ciphertext);

    BigInteger decrypted = test.decrypt(ciphertext);
    System.out.println("Plain text after decryption: " + decrypted);
}

public BigInteger encrypt(BigInteger plaintext) {

    return plaintext.modPow(e, n);
}

public BigInteger decrypt(BigInteger ciphertext) {

    return ciphertext.modPow(d, n);
}
}
```

The output is:

```
Plain text: 55 Ciphertext: 22 Plain text after decryption: 22
```

Comment: Your "plaintext=55" is greater than the "modulus=n=33" so what is actually getting encrypted is number 22 (55 mod 33). Also it so happens then 22 encrypted under modulus 33 is again 22.

Comment: The algorithm should be (pow(plaintext, pubKey) mod n), the first operation should be pow and then the mod operation is I'm not right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your plaintext (`55`) is larger than the the modulus (`33`), so you can't actually encrypt the message. Consider the following slightly different example:

- `p = 11`
- `q = 17`
- `n = 187`
- `phi(n) = 160`
- Choose `e = 3`
- If `d = 107` then `e * d = 321` = `1 mod phi(n)`

So change your code to:

```
  private BigInteger n = new BigInteger("187");
  private BigInteger e = new BigInteger("3");
  private BigInteger d = new BigInteger("107");

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    KeyTest test = new KeyTest();

    BigInteger plaintext = new BigInteger("55");
    System.out.println("Plain text: " + plaintext);

    BigInteger ciphertext = test.encrypt(plaintext);
    System.out.println("Ciphertext: " + ciphertext);

    BigInteger decrypted = test.decrypt(ciphertext);
    System.out.println("Plain text after decryption: " + decrypted);
  }

  public BigInteger encrypt(BigInteger plaintext) {

    return plaintext.modPow(e, n);
  }

  public BigInteger decrypt(BigInteger ciphertext) {

    return ciphertext.modPow(d, n);
  }
}
```

Output:

```
Plain text: 55
Ciphertext: 132
Plain text after decryption: 55
```

Comment: I understand now why after decryption in my code i am getting "wrong" answer, because it is impossible to calculate bigger number than 33 after mod 33 operation.